# Advanced Filtering in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Column A, I have 7000 rows of unique bore numbers. In Column D, I have 800 rows of bore numbers.(Column B & C contain data relating to Column A).

I want to filter the bore numbers in Column A to only include those bore numbers that are in Column D.

I have tried to use the advanced filter function in Excel, with my range selected as the 7000 rows in Column A and my criteria range as the 800 rows in Column D but the result just returns all the numbers in Column A.

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: The link does not appear. Please click [edit] and either give us an example, or a weblink we can use to see the data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-filtering answer:

Paste this into E2:

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,$A:$C,2,FALSE)
```

and this into F2:

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,$A:$C,3,FALSE)
```

Then copy E2 and F2 and paste down your 800 rows.